# Why does HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream always have length 0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, f#, httpcontext

Sorry, but I don't have a better description of my problem.  I'll edit the post if I discover something.

I am building an `F#-C# MVC4` application (in `Windows 8`, using `Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web`).  Everything was working without a problem.  I was making Ajax calls to post XML data to the server, by essentially doing the following on the server:

```ml
let str = (new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream,new UTFEncoding())).ReadToEnd()
let xr = XElement.Parse str
```

This was working perfectly, until about an hour ago.  I just got back to my desk after a snack, and now, the same call won't work anymore.  The error I get is that `InputStream` has `length 0'.

There is literally nothing else in the call stack.  The MVC template registers the routes in a file called `Global.fs`, in the following function:

```ml
type Global() =
    inherit System.Web.HttpApplication()
    static member RegisterRoutes (routes:RouteCollection) =
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")
        routes.MapRoute(
                        "Default",
                        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                        {controller = "Home"; action = "Index"; id=UrlParameter.Optional})
```

I don't want to clutter the post, but the controller and all the requisite functions are definitely present.

I have several other projects on my workstation which use the same `F#-C# MVC4` template, and they work perfectly.  And they have exactly the same set-up.

I have searched on Google, to no avail.  Any pointers as to how I can go about even trying to figure out `why InputStream has length 0` would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is anything else reading from the input stream earlier, perhaps? Have you looked at the network traffic with Wireshark/Fiddler2 to make sure that it's actually being passed by the client?

Comment: Even just look for open ports using nbtstat incase the port is dead etc: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940106.aspx

Comment: Why are you accessing low level APIs from MVC?

Comment: @JonSkeet, sorry, I had gone to bed.  I will check the network traffic and report back.

Comment: @7sharp9, I copied the same project over to Windows Server 2012 (running in a virtual machine on a different physical machine), and I got the same problem.

Comment: Do you have any form of AA control that might use Session? Would Session expiration play a role?

Comment: I downloaded and installed Wireshark.  I can post a screenshot of the output, but to make a long story short, I could not find any reason for my problem.  Then I shutdown my computer and restarted it.  Now the call works again!  I have no idea why shutting down helped (nor any idea why I didn't think to try it earlier).